# WPF: Launch code when IsMouseOver ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ComboBox.  Without changing the template, is there a way that I can launch code when there user places their mouse over a ComboBoxItem, but before the selection actually occurs?  It seems like I should be able to specify an EventTrigger or a Trigger to do this in the style of ComboBoxItem.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Voices}"                                
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVoice, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    ... Launch my code from code behind... but HOW? ...
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

I'm also ok with ousing a MouseEnter, but I would rather not build a separate DataTemplate or ContentTemplate if possible.

**Update.** The idea behind this snippet is to Play test audio when the user hovers over a new voice, which I would have to do from the code side.  Help!

Comment: how do you handle the case of a user moving the mouse over the first two items while going to the third one? Will you play the first two sounds?

Comment: the actual code will trigger a thread with thread.sleep which waits maybe 100-200 ms to make sure that the user is still on the same item, in this case, it will check if ismouseover is still true

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but two hints for realizing your idea: To play some audio on some event use the <EventTrigger> together with the <SoundPlayerAction> class. Alternatively use a <MediaElement> class and handle the mouse events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `EventSetter`:

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="ComboBoxItem_PreviewMouseMove" />
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

in code behind:

```
private void ComboBoxItem_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBoxItem item = sender as ComboBoxItem;
    //Now you can use this Item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know a dirty solution.. just in case you run out of solutions try this as your last hope..

I tested this by creating a `textblock` in `XAML` and setting its `text` equal to `content` of `comboboxitem` once `mouse` is `over` it and setting `text` to `""` once `mouse` has `left`

I am using `AttachedBehaviours` to find out on which particular `comboboxitem` is `mouse over` once mouse is there and also getting notified once mouse is not over it anymore or mouse is left

Try this.. create a class

```
 public static class ComboBoxBehaviour
    {
        //holding reference of MainWindow class to update the textBlock
        public static MainWindow windoewRef ;

        public static bool GetTest(ComboBoxItem target)
        {
            return (bool)target.GetValue(TestAttachedProperty);
        }

        public static void SetTest(ComboBoxItem target, bool value)
        {
            target.SetValue(TestAttachedProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestAttachedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Test", typeof(bool), typeof(ComboBoxBehaviour), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnMouseOverChanged));

        static void OnMouseOverChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBoxItem item = o as ComboBoxItem;
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                // I am setting text of a textblock for testing once mouse is over an item
                windoewRef.textBlock.Text = item.Content.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                //setting text to "" once mouse has been moved  
                windoewRef.textBlock.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

In XAML

```
 <TextBlock Text="" x:Name="textBlock" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="combo">

            <ComboBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" xmlns:behaviours="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter  Property="behaviours:ComboBoxBehaviour.Test" Value="True"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                            <Setter  Property="behaviours:ComboBoxBehaviour.Test" Value="False"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.Resources>
        </ComboBox>
```

I know this is a bad solution and it may have problems which I haven't found yet but just my thoughts...

Comment: Lol, that is pretty dirty, but I appreciate the solution.  ;)  Certainly one way is to re-create the Content or Data template.